# Mail not sending after changing the project directory name

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-authentication

I change the project name after copy and paste, and test to send the forgot your password email but got the error

```
(1/1) ErrorException
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error 
messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify 
failed
```

I try to fix by following other answers related to this issue but didn't get success

Answer (score 0):

Please clear the cache using below command

php artisan config:cache

php artisan view:clear

php artisan route:clear